# Add the ability to reply to a message on the star board

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars, reply

When clicking the dropdown arrow for a message in chat, you get the following menu:

[image: Image: Message dropdown, containing reply option]

If you click the dropdown for a message on the star board, you get this instead:

[image: Image: Star board dropdown]

I'd like the option to reply in the dropdown to a message on the star board. At the moment, the fastest way to reply is to open the message transcript in another tab and use the menu dropdown there. That, or scroll all the way up to wherever the message was in chat.

Another note: messages on the star board always have a link to "history", even if they haven't been edited, whereas other messages don't. Why aren't these menus consistent?